# I can't make a connection to SQL Server with my local IP in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I have one problem with C#

I connect `Data Source=BARIS;Initial Catalog=SurucuOtomasyon;User ID=sa;Password=1234`

But I don't connect database when i write mylocal ip to Data Source

```
Data Source=192.168.1.3;Initial Catalog=SurucuOtomasyon;User ID=sa;Password=1234
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm not trying to be unhelpful, but the is the classic 'Doctor is hurts when I do this.' and the Doctor says, then don't do that. Why can't you just use BARIS?

Answer (score 4):

[an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615398/sql-server-instance-name-with-ip-address)

Open your SQL Configuration Manager and allow to TCP/IP connections.
Set dynamic port blank to disable it (i don't remember here well) 
The IP gives the machine, you need a port, too:

192.168.1.3:1433 (the port 1433 is a standart)

[another link about connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

connection string with DataSource=192.168.2.3 is enough. You have to change configurationn. 
Right configuration will run your code. (i've tested it with a project, its all about configuration of your sql. See my comment below)

Comment: Port is enable. I try to connection to 192.168.1.3:1433 but this  problem don't solve

Comment: try your dynamic ip instead of local ip ... just for a try. tomorrow morning i will create a project for you and test everything. now i shall sleep.

Comment: This problem remote connection allow. How to allow remote connection ?

Comment: Thans for help icaptian. But today i will solve this problem because i won't sleep :)

Comment: Click at Sql Configuration Manager -> Sql Native Client [...] than from Sql Native Client[...] click -> TCP / IP you shall see default port as 1433. than you shall check Sql Server Network Protocol -> TCP / IP ... if you can't solve that problem i will look at tomorrow. By the way your question deserve many "-" :)